# Why does make ignore my modifications?

Tags: c++, bash, makefile

I am trying to use [E²LSH](http://www.mit.edu/~andoni/LSH/), here is the [manual](http://www.mit.edu/~andoni/LSH/manual.pdf). When untarred, the folder of this library has a Makefile, a bin folder and a source folder (among with other stuff).

In the source folder there is `LSHMain.cpp`, which I have to modify.

I deleted the project (just to make sure I haven't destroyed something), re-download it, modifying the file and then I hit make, but when I run the executable it is like all my modifications are gone and the original code is taken into account only!

This happens regardless of building the project from scratch or not.

I suspect that this has to do with the scripts inside bin folder, because I have to run it like this:

```
bin/lsh argument_list
```

What should I change?

Here is the Makefile (reduced, since some stuff is irrelevant)

```
SOURCES_DIR:=sources
OBJ_DIR:=bin
OUT_DIR:=bin
TEST_DIR:=$(SOURCES_DIR)

#H_SOURCES:=`find $(SOURCES_DIR) -name "*.h"`
#CPP_SOURCES:=`find $(SOURCES_DIR) -name "*.cpp"`
#TEST_SOURCES:=`find $(TEST_DIR) -name "*.cpp"`
OBJ_SOURCES:=$(SOURCES_DIR)/BucketHashing.cpp \
         $(SOURCES_DIR)/Geometry.cpp \
         $(SOURCES_DIR)/LocalitySensitiveHashing.cpp \
         $(SOURCES_DIR)/Random.cpp \
         $(SOURCES_DIR)/Util.cpp \
         $(SOURCES_DIR)/GlobalVars.cpp \
         $(SOURCES_DIR)/SelfTuning.cpp \
         $(SOURCES_DIR)/NearNeighbors.cpp

LSH_BUILD:=LSHMain

TEST_BUILDS:=exactNNs \
            genDS \
        compareOutputs \
        genPlantedDS

GCC:=g++
OPTIONS:=-O3 -DREAL_FLOAT -DDEBUG
# -march=athlon -msse -mfpmath=sse
LIBRARIES:=-lm 
#-ldmalloc

all: 
    bin/compile

c: compile

compile:
    @mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)
    $(GCC) -o $(OUT_DIR)/$(LSH_BUILD) $(OPTIONS) $(OBJ_SOURCES) $(SOURCES_DIR)/$(LSH_BUILD).cpp $(LIBRARIES)
    chmod g+rwx $(OUT_DIR)/$(LSH_BUILD)
```

and here are the compile and lsh scripts (inside the bin folder, the Makefile was in the same directory with source and bin folders):

```
#!/bin/bash

OUT_DIR=bin
SOURCES_DIR=sources
OBJ_SOURCES="$SOURCES_DIR/BucketHashing.cpp \
            $SOURCES_DIR/Geometry.cpp \
            $SOURCES_DIR/LocalitySensitiveHashing.cpp \
            $SOURCES_DIR/Random.cpp \
            $SOURCES_DIR/Util.cpp \
            $SOURCES_DIR/GlobalVars.cpp \
            $SOURCES_DIR/SelfTuning.cpp \
            $SOURCES_DIR/NearNeighbors.cpp"

TEST_BUILDS="exactNNs \
            genDS \
            compareOutputs \
            genPlantedDS"

defineFloat=REAL_FLOAT

g++ -o $OUT_DIR/testFloat -DREAL_FLOAT $OBJ_SOURCES $SOURCES_DIR/testFloat.cpp -lm >/dev/null 2>&1 || defineFloat=REAL_DOUBLE

OPTIONS="-O3 -D$defineFloat"

g++ -o $OUT_DIR/LSHMain $OPTIONS $OBJ_SOURCES $SOURCES_DIR/LSHMain.cpp -lm

chmod g+rwx $OUT_DIR/LSHMain

for i in $TEST_BUILDS; do
   g++ -o ${OUT_DIR}/$i $OPTIONS ${SOURCES_DIR}/${i}.cpp $OBJ_SOURCES -lm; chmod g+rwx $OUT_DIR/${i}; 

done
```

the lsh script

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=bin

if [ $# -le 2 ]; then
  echo Usage: $0 radius data_set_file query_set_file "[successProbability]"
  exit
fi

paramsFile=$2.params

if [ $# -ge 4 ]; then
 # success probability supplied
 $dir/lsh_computeParams $1 "$2" "$3" $4 > "$paramsFile" || exit 1
else
 # success probability not supplied
 $dir/lsh_computeParams $1 "$2" "$3" > "$paramsFile" || exit 1
fi

chmod g+rw "$paramsFile"

echo "R*******" >/dev/stderr
echo "R*********************" >/dev/stderr
echo "R-NN DS params computed." >/dev/stderr
echo "R*********************" >/dev/stderr
echo "R*******" >/dev/stderr

$dir/lsh_fromParams "$2" "$3" "$paramsFile"
```

---

EDIT_1

When I run `make` I get:

```
bin/compile
sources/LocalitySensitiveHashing.cpp: In function ‘RNNParametersT readRNNParameters(FILE*)’:
sources/LocalitySensitiveHashing.cpp:62:22: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
(many many warnings, but no errors, I have checked that I can execute the program afterwards)
```

With `make c` I got:

```
g++ -o bin/LSHMain -O3 -DREAL_FLOAT -DDEBUG sources/BucketHashing.cpp sources/Geometry.cpp sources/LocalitySensitiveHashing.cpp sources/Random.cpp sources/Util.cpp sources/GlobalVars.cpp sources/SelfTuning.cpp sources/NearNeighbors.cpp sources/LSHMain.cpp -lm 
warnings
chmod g+rwx bin/LSHMain
```

I really don't get why this didn't work....

With `make compile` I got:

```
g++ -o bin/LSHMain -O3 -DREAL_FLOAT -DDEBUG sources/BucketHashing.cpp sources/Geometry.cpp sources/LocalitySensitiveHashing.cpp sources/Random.cpp sources/Util.cpp sources/GlobalVars.cpp sources/SelfTuning.cpp sources/NearNeighbors.cpp sources/LSHMain.cpp -lm
warnings
chmod g+rwx bin/LSHMain
```

---

EDIT_2

the lsh_comouteParams is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

successProbability=0.9


if [ $# -le 1 ]; then
  echo Usage: $0 radius data_set_file "{query_set_file | .} [successProbability]"
  exit
fi

if [ $# -ge 4 ]; then
 # success probability supplied
 successProbability=$4
fi

arch=`uname`
nDataSet=` wc -l "$2"`
for x in $nDataSet; do nDataSet=$x; break; done
if [ "$3" != "." ]; then
  nQuerySet=` wc -l "$3"`
  for x in $nQuerySet; do nQuerySet=$x; break; done
else
  nQuerySet=0
fi
dimension=`head -1 "$2" | wc -w`

#echo $nDataSet $nQuerySet $dimension



if [ -e bin/mem ]; then
  m=`cat bin/mem`;
elif [ "$arch" = "Darwin" ]
then
  #http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1608380&tstart=0
  m=`top -l 1 | grep PhysMem | awk -F "[M,]" ' {print$10 }'`
  let m=m*1024*1024
  echo $m > bin/mem
else
  s=`free -m | grep "Mem:"`
  for i in $s; do m=$i; if [ "$i" != "Mem:" ]; then break; fi; done
  m=${m}000000
  echo $m > bin/mem
fi


bin/LSHMain $nDataSet $nQuerySet $dimension $successProbability "$1" "$2" "$3" $m -c
```

Comment: What output do you get when you run `make`? Are you running `make` or `make c` or `make compile`? Do things change if you run one of those latter two commands?

Comment: Updated @EtanReisner. Thanks for your time because I can't figure out why this happens for days.

Comment: What is in `bin/compile`? Is `bin/LSHMain` the binary that `bin/lsh` ends up running? What file are you editing?

Comment: I have the compile and lsh script in my question, isn't that what you mean? I am editting the `source/LSHMain.cpp`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. What is `bin/lsh_computeParams`? Does that run `bin/LSHMain`?

Comment: I am not sure @EtanReisner, I updated the question.

Comment: I would like the downvoter to give a solution too, not only his/her -1, since it's too easy in his/her eyes.

Comment: So that is running `bin/LSHMain` eventually. Are you sure your changes to `LSHMain.cpp` are something you should be hitting? If you delete `bin/LSHMain` and try to run `bin/lsh` does it fail? Does it work if you then run `make` or `bin/compile`? If you stick a `printf` or something else very obvious at the very start of `main` does it show up?

Comment: If you delete `bin/LSHMain` and try to run `bin/lsh` does it fail? That's exactly what I did today and I found what I was missing. I will answer my own question.

Comment: I will delete this comment. @EtanReisner I might find the solution myself, but if it wasn't for you, I am not sure if I had reached there. I will check your profile and upvote what I find interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had modified the file as such:

```
int main(int nargs, char **args){
printf("uoo\n");return 0;
  if(nargs < 9){
    usage(args[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  ...
}
```

When E²LSH doesn't receive the correct arguments, it won't run it's LSHMain (regardless the fact that there is a relevant code for that in that file - which what tricked me so badly, because I thought that I was reaching that point inside `main()`).

There is a script in bin folder which will take over and print the very same message as `usage()` would print, that's why I thought that I was reaching that call. The function call lies inside `if(nargs < 9)`, which made me to give in purpose less arguments so that it would sure fall inside that if and won't execute the algorithm (which takes time).

---

In short:

In order to reach the point that the code `source/LSHMain.cpp` gets executed one **must** pass the correct arguments to to `bin/lsh`. If not, `bin/lsh` script will only be executed, thus shadowing the modifications made in `source/LSHMain.cpp`.

Hope that this answer will make future users to avoid such a trap. Special thanks to Etan Reisner that helped me and eventually made me think to delete `source/LSHMain.cpp`, which made me to figure out what was happening.